# Center of the group algebra of the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials

How to prove that the center of the group algebra of the symmetric group is generated by 1-cycle conjugacy classes? I mean, that the center (consisting on class functions) is *multiplicatively* generated by classes of cycle permutations.

Comment: What are 1-cycle conjugacy classes?

Comment: 1-cycle is a permutation consisting of one cycle. We consider the element of the group algebra which is a sum of all permutations of a given cycle type.

Comment: This does not seem to be the same as the earlier question, which is to prove that the centre of the group algebra is generated by the sums of elements of all conjugacy classes, not just the $1$-cycle conjugacy classes.

Comment: Here https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0503040.pdf (p.11) it is claimed that this is a consequence of the fact that power sums from a multiplicative basis in the ring of symmetric functions, but I still don't understand how it works.